# Show that the closure of an open ball is exactly $B(0,R) := \{ x \in X : ||x|| \le R\}$

Tags: geometry, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space and
$$
 B(0,R) := \{ x \in X : ||x|| < R \} \qquad \overline{B}(0,R) := \{ x \in X : ||x|| \le R \}.
$$
I want to show that $\overline{B(0,R)} = \overline{B}(0,R)$. I already proofed the inclusion $\overline{B(0,R)} \subseteq \overline{B}(0,R)$, for the other inclusion I consider $x \in \overline{B}(0,R)$, then $||x|| \le R$, if $||x|| = R$ then I have to show that every ball around $x$ contains some different point from $B(0,R)$, but how can I be sure? What if the normed space is discrete, then there are no limit points at all?

Comment: Regarding your concern about the space being discrete: A normed space (indeed any [TVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space)) is discrete iff it's the trivial vector space.

Comment: The normed vector space is discrete iff it is $\{0\},$ and then $\ldots$

Comment: ahh okay i conjucted that something like that must be hold, but then i still does not know what ensures that every ball around $x$ contains another point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $X \neq 0$.

If $\lVert x \rVert = R$ and $\lambda \geq 0$ then $\lVert \lambda x\rVert = \lambda\lVert x \rVert = \lambda R$.

For $\lambda_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ we have $\lVert \lambda_n x \rVert \lt R$ and $\lambda_n x \to x$ because $\lVert x - \lambda_n x\rVert = \frac{1}{n}R \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$. This shows that $X$ is not discrete because it contains a non-constant convergent sequence. Moreover, every ball around $x$ intersects $B(0,R)$ non-trivially: given $r \gt 0$ we can choose $n$ so large that $0 \lt \frac{R}{n} \lt r$ so that $\lambda_n x \in B(0,R) \cap B(x,r)$ because $\lVert \lambda_n x\rVert = (1-\frac{1}{n})R \lt R$ and $\lVert x - \lambda_n x\rVert = \frac{1}{n}R \lt r$.